# Decimal input validation for cin?

Tags: c++, loops, validation

I'm trying to validate user input on how big an array should be. I'm checking to see if `size < 1` and if there is a decimal place in the code using:

```
int size = 0;
do {
    size = 0;
    cout << "Input an array size for your words array: ";
    cin >> size;
    if (floor(size) != size || size < 1) {
        cout << "Hey that's not a valid size!\n";
        cin.clear();
        cin.ignore(numeric_limits<streamsize>::max(), '\n');
    }
} while (floor(size) != size || size < 1);
```

The issue that I'm having is that numbers like -1, 0, .3 .9 all validate fine but numbers like 1.2 will have `size == 1` then the .2 being left in the queue. Is there a way to clear out these decimals? I have tried using just `size < 1` and the floor boolean by itself.

Thanks!

Comment: Whats the type of `size`?

Comment: @Swordfish Just edited, it's an int

Comment: The stream extractor (`>>`) for `int` will stop when it reaches any character that can’t be part of the text representation of an integer value. If someone types a decimal point that will end the conversion. Further, an `int` can only hold an integer value, so you don’t have to worry about a decimal place. `floor(size)` will always equal `size`.

Comment: Change the type of `size` to `double`.

Comment: @SidS wtf?? what for?? That won't help with other garbage being entered.

Comment: @Swordfish, it would solve the problem as he described it, and require minimal changes to his existing code.

Comment: @Sid It would still accept garbage entered.

Comment: @Swordfish, So ?  It solves the problem as he described it.

Comment: @SidS it doesn't

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When the user enters something like "1.2" and you try to extract an `int` from an input stream the stream extraction operator `>>` will successfully extract `1` and the rest stays in the input stream. So all you have to do is to check if what is left in the stream is anything other than whitespace.

```
#include <limits>
#include <cctype>
#include <iostream>

// This function peeks at the next character in the stream and only re-
// moves it from the stream if it is whitespace other than '\n'.
std::istream& eat_whitespace(std::istream &is)
{
    int ch;
    while ((ch = is.peek()) != EOF &&
           std::isspace(static_cast<unsigned>(ch)) && // Don't feed isspace()
           ch != '\n')                                // negative values!
    {
        is.get();
    }
    return is;
}

int main()
{
    int size;
    bool valid{ false };
    while (std::cout << "Input an array size for your words array: ",
           !(std::cin >> size >> eat_whitespace) ||
           size < 1 ||
           std::cin.get() != '\n') // since all whitespace has been eaten up
                                   // by eat_whitespace, the next character 
                                   // should be a newline. If it is not there 
                                   // is some other garbage left in the stream.
    {
        std::cerr << "Hey that's not a valid size!\n";
        std::cin.clear();
        std::cin.ignore(std::numeric_limits<std::streamsize>::max(), '\n');
    }
}
```